# how to dump a case-sensitive table within a specific schema

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, pg-dump

I'm trying to dump a case-sensitive table named `app_auth.User` by executing the following command

```
pg_dump --schema=app_auth -t '"User"' -U em3local -h 127.0.0.1 -Fc -a -f <path> <dbname>
```

but what I'm returned is:

```
pg_dump: No matching tables were found
```

If I actually query my DB, the table does exist:

```
<dbname>=# SELECT * FROM app_auth."User";
 username | email | password | name | surname | lang | resettoken | userinfo_id | state | tos_accepted | id 
----------+-------+----------+------+---------+------+------------+-------------+-------+--------------+----
```

any hint?

Comment: Try `-t 'app_auth."User"'`

Comment: ^ Confusingly you can put a period in your table name too. So `app_auth.User` is resolving to `public."app_auth.User"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you specifies the schema name to unload it does not mean that it will be default schema to search objects:

```
nd@postgres=# create schema foobar;
CREATE SCHEMA
nd@postgres=# create table foobar."Foo"();
CREATE TABLE
nd@postgres=# \! pg_dump --schema=foobar -t "Foo"
pg_dump: no matching tables were found
```

So you should to fully qualify the table name:

```
nd@postgres=# \! pg_dump --schema=foobar -t 'foobar."Foo"'
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--
... etc ...
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) (cursive and bold is mine):

> The -n and -N *(--schema)* switches have no effect when -t is used, because tables selected by -t will be dumped regardless of those switches, and non-table objects will not be dumped.
>
> Formerly, writing -t tab would dump all tables named tab, **but now it just dumps whichever one is visible in your default search path**.

Comment: what did I do worng
```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost --schema=public -t='public."AdminEmailTempaltes"' --data-only --column-inserts deployedspovix1 > data.sql
```